# graph (chartjs.org) does not stretch properly when sidebar(menu) is collapsed

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, chart.js

I am trying to create a simple sidebar menu with bootstrap and add responsive content on the right, but have been stuck with the issue when graph/canvas does not stretch full width within it's container when menu is collapsed. that said, I know I need somehow to render the graph again but I was unfortunately not able to sort it out :( I have also tried to resize canvas with jscript but the problem persists. any help would be appreciated :)

here is a simple jscript I use to collapse/expand the sidebar

```
/*COLLAPSE/EXPAND MENU*/
$("#menu-toggle,#menu-toggle-collapsed").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    $("#menu-toggle-collapsed").toggleClass("visible-xs");
});
```

here is the working example and the rest of the code. try to collapse the sidebar to see what I am talking about
https://jsfiddle.net/ob0w8thn/9/

and yes graph is set to be responsive within global options

```
maintainAspectRatio: true,
responsive: true,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `responsive: true` does trigger a chart resize (to fit its wrapper), this handler is attached to the window resize event. You just need to do whatever this code does in the CSS transition end. Something like

```
$("#wrapper").on('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd', function () {
      myLineChart.resize(myLineChart.render, true);
});
```

---

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/k2kjz8s3/

---

**Note** : The transition end event triggers for **EACH** transitioned property. So if you have 2 animated properties (say padding / width), the above is going to trigger twice.

This is not a problem for the `resize()` (besides it running twice), but if you are adding any other functionality that is not idempotent, it will cause problems. In this case you should be listening for any one of the transitioned properties, like so

```
function redrawGraph(evt) {
     if (evt.originalEvent.propertyName == 'width') {
     ...
```