# chartjs removing/redrawing canvas, graph not responsive

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, chart.js

I have been trying to remove and redraw canvas but I can not make it responsive.

```
var testChart = document.getElementById('testLine').getContext('2d');
var myLineChart = new Chart(testChart).Line(lineData);
$("#testLine").remove();
$("#graph-container").html("<canvas id='testLine'></canvas>");
var testChart1 = document.getElementById('testLine').getContext('2d');
var myLineChart1 = new Chart(testChart1).Line(lineData);
```

both responsive and mantainaskectratio are set to true

```
responsive: true,
maintainAspectRatio: true
```

this is a simplified version of my code but I can not make it work. it's important to note that .destroy() or .clear() methods dont fit my needs!

here is a live example and the entire test code
https://jsfiddle.net/ob0w8thn/11/

Comment: When I resize the window AND reload the page the chart stretches to fill the entire content width. What way do you feel it's not working as expected? Cheers!

Comment: it should be responsive while resizing the window as by default, I dont want to reload page :)

Comment: if I dont remove and redraw canvas it works flawlessly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it's important to note that .destroy() or .clear() methods dont fit my
>   needs!

I think there's something wrong going on here. The underlying problem here is that you are not destroying the chart you created first i.e. `testChart`. Simply removing the node does not clean it up completely.

---

Chart.js internally stores all instances of the charts created. When you resize the window, Chart.js loops through this list running a resize on each instance. In your code above, it errors out because the first instance is no longer in the DOM and the resize is never triggered for the 2nd instance `testChart2`

I'd strongly suggest you evaluate why you can't do a `.destroy()` (this simply removes the instance from Chart.js internal list) before doing the `.remove()`.

However, if there is some reason you can't call a `.destroy()`, you can do one of the below

---

**Option 1**

Write your own window resize handler that triggers resize for the chart instances you want, like so

```
Chart.helpers.addEvent(window, "resize", (function () {
    var timeout;
    return function () {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(function () {
            myLineChart1.resize(myLineChart1.render, true);
        }, 50);
    };
})());
```

**Option 2**

Rewrite the `getMaximumWidth` function in the **Chart.js library** to add a try catch block, like so (just search for the first line to locate the block)

```
getMaximumWidth = helpers.getMaximumWidth = function (domNode) {
    try {
        var container = domNode.parentNode;
        // TODO = check cross browser stuff with this.
        return container.clientWidth;
    }
    catch (err)
    {}
},
```

**Option 3**

Remove the responsive option for the chart before removing it's node, like so

```
myLineChart.options.responsive = false;
$("#testLine").remove();
```

While this doesn't remove the unnecessary reference from the Chart.js internal list, it prevents Chart.js from triggering an (unnecessary) error causing resize for an instance that doesn't exist in the DOM.

---

Here's Option 3 in action

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/0vfqw61q/

Comment: I simply dont know why it does not work with .destroy(), it's driving me nuts :( yes your option 3 works on this simple example but it does not with my code and I have no idea why! that said, what I want to achieve is to remove graph on click `$("selector").click(function(e)...` and redraw it using another function `$(function(){$("selector").on("transitionend...`

Comment: hm.. try option 2 then - search for the 1st line in the Chart.js file and copy paste in what is missing.

Comment: cant sort it out, whatever I try it simply does not work :(

Comment: you replied to my previous question where I have issue with resizing the graph ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31957578/graph-chartjs-org-does-not-stretch-properly-when-sidebarmenu-is-collapsed ). even though your solution works, it does not fit my needs, hence I want to remove the canvas on click event and redraw it on transitionend but the graph is not responsive and I have no idea why! here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ob0w8thn/15/

Comment: Er.. the fiddle in your comment seems to work fine. The chart disappears and reappears with the correct size when the animation is complete. Checked in IE and Chrome. Am I missing something?

Comment: try to resize the window, graph is not responsive after you click to collapse/expand menu!

Comment: Changed the last function - see https://jsfiddle.net/jo8q4h0b/. The problem was 2 fold - 1.the transitionend triggers for each animated property, 2. resizing triggers your tab collapse / expand adding an extra chart instance.  I'll add a note to my other answer. Cheers!

Comment: it looks like it works :) will test it thoroughly! I tried to add `if (evt.originalEvent.propertyName == 'width')...` but I was missing `if (myLineChart)` hence it did not work!

Comment: Yeah, strange that the collapse triggers. There is a neater way of doing this than global variables though - just loop through the Chart instances (available in `Chart.instances`) and match based on the parentNode of the canvas element. However global variables are an acceptable compromise if you have only 1 chart that you manage with that global variable.

Comment: I have one graph and one chart, I still did not try if it works with both...will check out `Chart.instances`. dont worry when I test it I will mark it as solved!